# Nuxtjs error - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm using vedraggable, so I have two draggables on the page, one to clone and the other that just receives the clone.

The draggable that receives has a @change, calling a method that changes a vuex variable with the value of this component's variable. This vuex variable is only receiving the value, it is not used.
When it is changed the first time, it works, the second time the error '[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.'

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names -->
<template>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <draggable
        :list="lista"
        :group="{ name: 'people', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
        
        @start="drag = true"
        @end="drag = false"
    >
        <div class="element" v-for="(element, index) in lista" :key="index">
            {{ element.name }}
        </div>
    </draggable>

    <draggable
        class="ml-5"
        :list="lista3"
        group="people"
        @change="muda"
        
        @start="drag = true"
        @end="drag = false"
    >
        <div class="element" v-for="(element, index) in lista3" :key="index">
            {{ element.name }}
        </div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
    components: {
        draggable,
    },

    data(){
        return{
            lista: [
                {
                id: 1,
                name: "Teste 1",
                },
                {
                id: 2,
                name: "Teste 2",
                },
            ],

            lista3: []
        }
    },

    methods: {
        ...mapMutations(['SET_LISTA_PESSOAS']),

        muda(){
            this.SET_LISTA_PESSOAS(this.lista3)
            console.log(this.$store.state.listaPessoas)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Vuex

```
export const state = () => ({
  listaPessoas: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_LISTA_PESSOAS(context, payload){
    context.listaPessoas = payload
  },
}
```

Comment: What is `SET_LISTA_PESSOAS` doing exactly? Maybe it's modifying a reference rather than a copy value?

Comment: ready, add the code, it's from vuex

Comment: Rather than erasing the `listaPessoas` array by the payload one, try rather to `push` the elements of `lista3` into it.